# largest semisimple quotient of a projective module is a projective envelope

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $P$ be a projective module (over a noncommutative ring!), $K$ a submodule, and $P/K$ its maximal semisimple quotient module.

Can there exist a proper submodule $Q\subsetneq P$ such that $Q\twoheadrightarrow P/K$?

Suppose such a $Q$ exists, and we may choose $Q$ to be minimal w.r.t. the property that it surjects onto $P/K$. By projectivity of $P$, there is a map $a : P\rightarrow Q$, which by minimality of $Q$ must be a surjection.

It would suffice to show that the natural map $Q\hookrightarrow P$ is a section to $a$, though I don't see why this needs to be true.

I'm happy to assume everything is finitely generated.

Comment: Choosing a minimal such $Q$ sounds potentially problematic... inverse limits (which an intersection is an example of) are not right exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $P$ may not have a maximal semisimple quotient (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have a maximal semisimple quotient).

I'll assume that you're interested in cases where it does, in which case it has a unique maximal semisimple quotient $P/K$, since if $P/K_1$ and $P/K_2$ are semisimple, then so is $P/(K_1\cap K_2)$, and so every semisimple quotient of $P$ is a quotient of $P/K$.

If $P$ is finitely generated, and $Q$ is a proper submodule, then $P/Q$ has a simple quotient, and so $Q$ can not map surjectively to $P/K$.

For $P$ not finitely generated, there may be a proper submodule $Q$ that maps surjectively to $P/K$. For example, over the $p$-adic integers, let $\pi:P\to\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a surjection from a projective $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, and let $Q=\ker(\pi)$. Since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has no simple quotient, every non-zero map from $P$ to a simple module has non-zero restriction to $Q$, and so $Q$ maps surjectively to $P/K$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your argument that if $P$ has a maximal semisimple quotient then it must be unique.  If $P/K_1,P/K_2$ are semisimple why must $P/(K_1\cap K_2)$ be also?  Extensions of semisimple modules are not necessarily semisimple.

Comment: @freeRmodule There's a natural injective map $P/(K_1\cap K_2)\to P/K_1\oplus P/K_2$, and submodules of semisimple modules are semisimple.